# android application stopped working not showing demo on emulator

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-layout

what is wrong with coding...here is my java page
plz help me as i m a beginner and i m feeling confused.....
i m making a simple add  1 and sub 1 app folowing travis (the new boston) youtube tutuorials....xml code in it showing 9 warnings as i m nt using string with text as travis sir nt used it in his tutorials...

```
int counter;
Button add, sub;
TextView display;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    counter =0;
    add = (Button) findViewById("R.id.bAdd");
    sub = (Button) findViewById("R.id.bSub");
    display = (TextView) findViewById("R.id.tvDisplay");
    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View v){
            //TODO Auto-generated method stub
            counter++;
            display.setText("Your total is" + counter);
        }
    });
    sub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View v){
            //TODO Auto-generated method stub
            counter--;
            display.setText("Your total is" + counter);
        }
    });
}

private TextView findViewById(String string) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
```

}

**here is my .xml page**

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvDisplay"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Your total is 0" 
    android:textSize="45dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    ></TextView>

<Button
      android:layout_width="250dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="add one"
      android:textSize="20dp"
      android:layout_gravity="center"
      android:id="@+id/bAdd" >

  </Button>


  <Button
      android:layout_width="250dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="Sub one"
      android:textSize="20dp"
      android:layout_gravity="center"
      android:id="@+id/bSub">

  </Button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`findViewById` takes an int argument not a string:

```
findViewById(R.id.bAdd);
```

Comment: i removed this part private TextView findViewById(String string) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

Comment: but it is again showing errors that findViewById is not applicable for the arguments

Comment: @user3427015 What? All you had to do is to remove quotes from the arguments you are sending to `findViewById` method, like in my example, only for all calls.

Comment: thnx a lot sir as i m a beginner and i was searching for error frm last 5 hrs you helped me a lot .thnx 4r ur patience..

Comment: @user3427015 you are welcome but you could have easily found this by looking at some examples at the [Android Docs](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html). Happy coding!